# Static HTML page caching for large website

Tags: cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I'm creating a WooCommerce store with 3000+ products (+filters). And I'm using WP super cache plugin because I want to serve pages as fast as possible.

This arises problems/questions:

- When any post is edited - WP Super Cache purges all cache and regenerates thousands of pages again. Is there any way to control which files should be regenerated on post update? (e.g. regenerate just its product page)
- Am I doing it all wrong? Maybe I shouldn't use WP Super Cache for such large website at all, do you have any recommendations?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In `Settings` > `WP Super Cache` disable `Advanced` > `Clear all cache files when a post or page is published or updated`.

There is nothing wrong with using static page cache for larger site as long as it fits your requirements. If you need dynamic features or extreme performance, then it would be time to look into alternatives.